# Error: Cannot find module 'swiper/react' in next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js, swiper.js

After upgrading Swiper to Version `7.0.7`, I'm getting this annoying error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'swiper/react'
.
.
.
Source

.next\server\pages\items.js (1:0) @ Object.swiper/react
> 1 | module.exports = require("swiper/react");
```

In the previous Version (`6.8`) I didn't see this error. I also checked the [migration guide](https://swiperjs.com/migration-guide#node-es-modules) and github issues but found no helpful answer.

The thing is "import cost" extension in VSCode is showing the size of the imported module, so I think there's a problem with Next.js or webpack exporting it, but have no idea how to make it work.

I copy/pasted the exact code from Swiper docs, but will write it here too if it helps:

```
/* _app.js - imported here because Next doesn't allow global css imports elsewhere */
import 'swiper/scss';
```

```
/* slider component which is used inside pages/items.js */
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"; /* 72.4k (gzipped 21.4k) */

export default function CategoriesBar() {
   return (
      <Swiper
         spaceBetween={50}
         slidesPerView={3}
         onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
         onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      >
         <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
         <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
         <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
         <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
   );
}
```

## Update

after upgrading Next.js to `11.1.2`, the error message changed to:
`Error: Not supported`

Comment: Thanks, @brc-dd. Yeah, I just saw the issue here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9607. Anyways, may you please explain how can I "transpile" it?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you doing? I am not able to reproduce it: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mestorf-pdh06?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Check My answer @brc-dd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It was **not related to next.js nor webpack**. ESM modules support started from `Node.js 12.20` and mine was `12.16`. Upgraded my Node.js installation & everything is working fine now!

https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

Comment: How did you solve the Eslint error?

I am using Swiper v7 with Next.js and Eslint but it gives me an import error that cannot resolve the path.

Comment: I think it's better to ask a new question for that and included your code + error there as well. In my case, the error was not related to next, nor webpack nor eslint. My problem was the outdated Node.js version.